# Converting tree-like map into plain map with composite keys

Tags: java, dictionary, mapping, logic

I was trying to do something in Java but I am stuck at this problem, I really dont know how to convert this. I tried for loops but I would need to make a lot of for loops and I would like to keep my code clean.

I have a Map that looks like this.

```
Map 1:
  A: Object
  B: Object
  C: Map 2
     D: Object
     E: Object 
     F: Map 3
        G: Object
        (Here could be another map that could go really far, etc)
     H: Map 4
        I: Object
        J: Object
        (Here could also be more)\
     K: Object
     (Here could also be more)
```

Note that this is just an example, the amount of maps, keys, etc can differ and so can the key names. The key names can't contain dots.

C, F and H are maps where map C contains D, E, F, H, K and map F contains G, etc.

How to convert this to ONE Map that looks like:

```
A: Object
B: Object
C.D: Object
C.E: Object
C.K: Object
C.F.G: Object
C.H.I: Object
C.H.J: Object
```

The order of the keys doesn't matter.

Comment: recursively concatenate keys and put into your map.

Comment: Try recursive implementation with going into maps... You schould also post what you have done...

Comment: But how would I make it so it goes as far as possible? Make a lot of for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
public Map<String, Object> convert (Map<String, Object> input, String key) {
    Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();

    for (Entry<String, Object> e : input.entrySet()) {
        String newKey = key == "" ? e.getKey() : (key + "." + e.getKey());

        if (e.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            res.putAll(convert((Map) e.getValue(), newKey));  // recursive call
        } else {
            res.put(newKey, e.getValue());
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now you call it on your input map:

```
Map<String, Object> converted = convert(input, "");
```

Comment: do you mean convert instead of distribute on line 5?

Comment: Missing return statement

Comment: Thanks guys for review! Corrected everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along those lines
Let's say that your map is
Map

```
    public class ObjectMapper
    {
    Map<Integer,Object> subMap;
    }
```

Admitting that your object can be a string or a map
Say that you invoke the "path" to an object like this
"1#2#4#5"

```
    Map<Integer, Object> someMap;

    //assign map or load it from somewhere
    String searchPath = "1#2#4#5";
    String[] splitPath = searchPath .split("#");
    String searchResult = null;
    boolean resultFound = false;
    boolean resultWrongPlace = false;

    Map<Integer, Object> mapToSearch = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < splitPath.length; i++)
    {
    if (resultFound == true)
      {
         resultWrongPlace = true;
         break;
      }
      if (i == 0)
      {
        mapToSearch = someMap;
      }
      Object currentObj = mapToSearch.get(splitPath[Integer.parseInt(splitPath[i])])
      if (currentObj instanceof String)
      {
         searchResult = (String) currentObj ;
         resultFound = true;
      }
      else if (currentObj instanceof ObjectMapper)
      {
         mapToSearch = (ObjectMapper) currentObj ;
         resultFound = false;
      }
    }
    if (resultFound == true && resultWrongPlace == true)
    {
    throw new Exception("result was found but the path that lead to a  result was different from the indended path!");
    }
    else if (resultFound == false)
    {
    throw new Exception("no result was found searching your expression path!");
    }
```

I'd say something along those lines will do the trick

Comment: Nice, but here you query tree-like map, not convert it into a flat map.

Comment: yes, I think that Sasha Salauyou it's more elegant :)
Unfortunately I wrote this in pseudo-code and took me more time than his 9 codelines solution, so I didn't notice that he answered correctly before posting mine.. sorry for the spam..